# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, html

The above error is getting displayed in my console each time I try to run the code to target a form input value in the html using javascript for my weather app. Below is code snippet. How can I solve this error?

Html:

```
<div class="slocation"> 
             <form class="search-location">
               <input
                  type="text"
                  name="city"
                  size="50"
                  placeholder="City name"
                  autocomplete="off"
                class="form-control"/>
                <span><button type="submit" >GO</button></span> 
              </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    const searchForm = document.querySelector('.search-location');
    //const citySearched = searchForm.querySelector('input[="text]').value;
    const cityValue = searchForm.querySelector('.search-location input');
    const cityName = cityValue.querySelector('.location p h2');
     

    updatewatherApp = (city) => {
        cityname.textcontent = city.name;
        // console.log(city.name);
    }

    // add an event listener to the form
    searchForm.addEventListener('submit', e=> {
        e.preventDefault();
    // or searchForm.addEventListener('submit', (event)=> {
    // event.preventDefault();
     
        const value = searchForm.querySelector('.search-location[type="text]').value;
        const citySearched = cityValue.Value.trim();
        console.log(citySearched);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this solution by debugging. I can see that JS cannot read a property 'value' of some HTMLFormElement.

Next, I would look into the code to see where I have I tried to access the 'value' property.

It appears that I have tried to access the value property of an object in the below line

```
const value = searchForm.querySelector('.search-location[type="text]').value
```

From the error message, I know that `searchForm.querySelector('.search-location[type="text]')` is `null` because the error is 'Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLFormElement.'

Next, I can do a

```
console.log('Search Location Text Element', searchForm.querySelector('.search-location[type="text]'))
```

and I can see in the console that null is printed!! Yes! I found the error.

Now, we need to correct the query selector so that we get the correct element and not null.

```
'.search-location[type="text]'
```

I can see two problems with this query selector:

1. `text` is not enclosed in `" "`. The closing `"` is missing.
2. The query selector will search for an element having CSS 'search-location' class and an attribute `type` whose value is `text` which is missing from our defined HTML.

So, we can correct the query selector to

```
'input[name="city"]'
```

Then we can have multiple inputs in our form and we can select each by name.

Using my previous work experience in JS, I know that we don't have a property `Value` for HTML Elements by default in JS.
So, I would go ahead and change the line

```
const citySearched = cityValue.Value.trim();
```

to

```
const citySearched = cityValue.value.trim();
```

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3pLfj9o/) with the updated and working code.

PS: I tried to show you an approach of how to think and debug instead of posting a direct solution.

Comment: I feel you wanted me to change" const citySearched = cityValue.Value.trim();" to something else. Please check your recommendation above. the new error now is  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> "

Comment: OOh  euraka just got it, no more null error. I removed the trim().  thanks a lot

Comment: @oodafe glad that it helped!